# My highlighted current date via javascript is not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have successfully managed (with the help from stack overflow) to loop through a calendar starting from may until end oktober 2015. now i want to highlight the current date which is 28 june sunday. but for some reason it highlights the wrong date and i don't think its because of the code but i am not a 100% sure.

checkout this link to see it visually (http://gyazo.com/30e448d0f84c8f1c55e4dd1ce6d91f38)

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/GY22/vqfk8yLL/

this is my html code:

```
<ul id="timeline">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

this is my javascript code:

```
<script>

// Get today's current date.
var now = new Date();
console.log(now);

// Calculates the number of the week
var weekNumber = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
console.log("The current week number is: " + weekNumber);

// Array list of months.
var month = new Array(12);
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
//console.log(month[3]);

var weekDay = new Array(7);
weekDay[0]=  "Su";
weekDay[1] = "Mo";
weekDay[2] = "Tu";
weekDay[3] = "We";
weekDay[4] = "Th";
weekDay[5] = "Fr";
weekDay[6] = "Sa";

function formatDate(date) {
    var month = date.getUTCMonth() +1;
    var dayNumber = date.getUTCDate();
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var day = date.getUTCDay();
    return weekDay[day] + ": " + dayNumber + "-" + month + "-" + year + ";  ";
    //return weekDay[day] + " " + dayNumber + ";  "; 
}
//console.log(formatDate(new Date()));

var today

function addListItem(){
    var createListItem = document.createElement("li");
    var outputListItem = document.createTextNode(today);

    createListItem.appendChild(outputListItem);
    var createUl = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    createUl[0].appendChild(createListItem);
}

// loop starting from may up untill for months from the set date
for (var i = 0; i < 122; i++){
    today = formatDate(new Date(2015, 05, i));
    //document.write(today + "<br />");
    addListItem();
}

document.getElementById('timeline').
getElementsByTagName('li')[(new Date()).getDate() - 1].className += ' currentDate';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line from:

```
getElementsByTagName('li')[(new Date()).getDate() - 1].className += ' currentDate';
```

To:

```
getElementsByTagName('li')[(new Date()).getDate() + 1].className += ' currentDate';
```

The date appeared to be off by just one day before, so that should fix it.

Comment: Hoegan, i did have to do +2 but it is doing what i want now ;-)

Comment: This whole line of code doesn't make sense. Why are you using the day of the month as an index selector? The current selected date will be more and more offset every day.

Comment: @NGPixel, not sure how else to achieve what i want thats why i am doing this way but if you have a better solution i would appreciate it

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution. Your current line will again be off once you move to the next month.

Comment: I will admit that your way appears to be the easier way to do it, and it will simplify some of the code. Maybe setting i = to 1 in the for loop will be a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MomentJS instead. It would save you a lot of code and date problems:

http://momentjs.com/

If you prefer to keep your code, move your current date logic inside your addListItem() method.

```
if(today == formatDate(new Date())) {
    createListItem.className += ' currentDate';
}
```

Comment: i want to highlight the current date of today but for some reason its highlighting 25 june a thursday

Comment: i added your bit of code in to the AddListItem() method but then it does not loop through all the dates. check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/GY22/vqfk8yLL/1/

Comment: Try with the edited code. First variable is already formatted.